# Image effects within a single div using jquery function .fadeIn/Out .delay(300)

Tags: jquery, image

I need to know if the following is possible using jQuery and how it can be achieved.

I have a `<div>` with an `id="divid"` and inside it is an `<image source="images/myimage01.jpg">`.

What I need is a script that can load/loop a series of images `<img src="images/images01.jpg>` to `<img src="images/images10.jpg">` from `<image source="images/theimages.jpg">` inside my `<div id"divid">` using the `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut` functiona.

I hope this is posible. I dont want to have to us flash or put a gallery there.

Comment: would be nice for some feedback on the answers given

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kQBQj/

```
var divs = $('#divid img').hide(),
    len = divs.length;

function rotate( i ) {
    divs.eq( i ).fadeIn(800, function() {
        divs.eq( i ).delay( 300 ).fadeOut(500, function() {
           rotate( ++i % len );
        });
    });
}
rotate( 0 );
```

Right now, once the image a faded in, there's a 300ms delay before it fades out and goes to the next.

If you want it longer, just change the value in `.delay( 300 )`. I only used it because it was in the title.

Comment: Note that you could shorten it a little by eliminating one of the callbacks. http://jsfiddle.net/kQBQj/1/ Also, not sure why I named the variable `divs` when it is referencing the images. :oP

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zp3XJ/

Just give each image an ID

```
<img src="images/image01.jpg" id="image1" class="slideImage"/>
<img src="images/image02.jpg" id="image2" class="slideImage"/>
```

Then style the images to be invisible

```
.slideImage{display:none;}
```

Once you do that, you can simply show the images this way. Each time you call the function, the imageIndex will increase by one, check to see if the image exists (if it doesn't, reset the index to 1), and fade the image in, wait 300ms and fade the image out.

```
var imageIndex=0;

showNextImage();

function showNextImage(){

    imageIndex++;

    if ( $('#image' + imageIndex).length==0) imageIndex=1;

    $('#image' + imageIndex).fadeIn().delay(300).fadeOut('fast',function(){
        showNextImage();        
    });
}
```